# Django-ckeditor not saving edits with crispy-forms

Tags: javascript, django, django-crispy-forms, django-ckeditor

I have a cripsy form and I want to change one field from `Textarea` to `CKEDitorUploadingWdidget`

So my form looks like this (I have left in what was previoulsy working:

```
class RenameStudyForm(BetterModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Study Name', max_length=51, required=False) # Update study name
    #waiver = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Waiver of Documentation', required=False) 
    waiver = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget(), label='Waiver of Documentation', required=False)
```

I have amended my model as follows:

```
class study(models.Model):
    researcher = models.ForeignKey("auth.user") # Researcher's name
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 51) # Study name
    instrument = models.ForeignKey("instrument") # Instrument associated with study
    #waiver = models.TextField(blank = True) 
    waiver = RichTextUploadingField(blank = True)
```

My template looks has:

```
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {{ form.media }}
    {% crispy form %}
```

When I enter the screen to edit the waiver I get a rich text field to edit, as I would expect.  However, nothing I enter into the field is passed back to the form.  Within the form I added a print statement, as below

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RenameStudyForm, self).clean()
    print(cleaned_data['waiver'])
```

The print always gives the original text.  Can anyone help me please

**EDIT**

I've been reviewing console when I'm using the CKEditorUploadingWidget against the forms.Textarea widget and it appears to be generating the following jQuery warning

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

I believe I am getting this because I am loading the form into a modal using this button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"   onclick = "modal_form('/interface/study/{{ current_study|urlencode }}/rename_study/')" >Update Study</button>
```

And this view

```
def rename_study(request, study_name):
    #do stuff
    return render(request, 'researcher_UI/add_study_modal.html', form_package)
```

So my JavaScript for ckeditor is being loaded now rather than when the document is originally loaded so I think this causes the issues.  Any thoughts really appreciated

Comment: Are you receiving other fields in the `clean(self)`?

Comment: Yes, everything else is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  The form is being submitted via ajax.  As such I need to copy the CKEditor data into the form field, which I do with

```
for (var instance in CKEDITOR.instances){
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```